# Which Result Content types are valid for discovery and which are valid for non-discovery retrieves?

Tags: onem2m

The oneM2M specs (various versions) seem to be very unclear about what should be returned for various combinations of `rcn` & `fu` flags.

can some please clarify? possibly with pointers to spec sections?

for example:

In TS-0001 v2.27, section 8.1.2, the only 'Result Content' type description that mentions discovery is `child-resource-references` which says "This option can be used within the context of resource discovery mechanisms". Does this imply that none of the other Result Content types can be used within the context of resource discovery mechanisms, since their descriptions do not explicitly allow this?

If that is the case, then why does TS-0004, section (7.2.1.2) talk about both `URIList` and `resourceRefList` in Discovery responses? These two things seem to be in conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per my discussion with @andreas-kraft, the answer is:

- attributes
- attributes+child-resources
- attributes+child-resource-references
- child-resource-references (default)
- original-resource
- child-resources
- semantic-content

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at TS-0001 **v4.4.0** table 8.1.2-1 "Summary of Result Content Values". This table, and the text above it, gives an overview about which result content types are allowed for which request type.

Some of the RCN types return just references (or attributes + references). In this case some resource attributes as well as a list of URI's (resource ID's) is returned.

Comment: yeah, this version of the table i mentioned above has the same issue: only the descriptions for `child-resource-references` and `discovery-result-references` mention that they can be used with discovery requests. does that mean that all other Result Content Values are invalid in discovery requests?
it would be great if that table had separate columns for 'Discovery' and 'non-Discovery retrieve'.

Comment: This table shows the allowed combinations for discovery requests. For some types it is mentioned in the text that they can be used in discovery, but this doesn't mean that the other types are not allowed. Please note, that discovery is defined for all request types, not only RETRIEVE!

Comment: "This table shows the allowed combinations for discovery requests" i'm not seeing that. i see columns for "value", "create", "retrieve", "update", "delete", "notify". are you saying that _every_ "valid" entry is valid for discovery? where does it say that in the spec? also, why would the description for `child-resource-references` specifically mention "This option can be used within the context of resource discovery mechanisms" if that's the case for all the others also? it's really ambiguous.

Comment: In section 8.1.2, above the table: "Settings of Result Content depend on the requested operation specified in Operation." The term "discovery" is used when applying filter in a retrieve operation. When applying filter in create, update or delete operations, this is called "discovery-based". Then, to quote the spec in 10.2.6 "If one or more target resources are identified the Hosting CSE shall respond with a successful response with the response content based on the Result Content and the Desired Identifier Result Type request parameters." And, not all rcn types make sense for every operation.

Comment: again, "are you saying that every 'valid' entry (in table 8.1.2) is valid for discovery" ? i don't see that in the spec, and the text "This option can be used within the context of resource discovery mechanisms" implies that at least some of the other options CANNOT be used within the context of resource discovery mechanisms. maybe it's just a language thing. if they're all ok in discovery why doesn't it just say that? if some of them are not ok in discovery why doesn't it list those?

Comment: 8.1.2 is part of the normative spec, so, yes, table 8.1.2-1 is normative as well. And yes, "valid" entries are allowed/must be supported. Discovery is actually a two-step process: 1) filtering 2) preparation of the result. How the second step is performed is determined by the rcn argument.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215262/discussion-between-spongman-and-andreas-kraft).